# What does 'context' exactly mean in C# async/await code?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, synchronizationcontext

Lets looks at some simple C# async/await code where I have an object reference (`obj`) before and after an `await` with `ConfigureAwait(false)`

```
private async Task<SomeObject> AnAsyncLibraryMethod(SomeObject obj)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    obj.Name = "Harry"; // <-- obj here

    // MAIN POINT
    var newSubObj = await FetchOverHttpAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    // Continuation here
    Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    obj.Name = "Sally"; // <-- same obj here
    return obj;
}

public class SomeObject { public string Name; }
```

`ConfigureAwait(false)` seems to means **NOT** *marshal the continuation back to the original context captured* - ok, but what does that really mean? I've tried the code above and `obj` **IS** correctly referenced back (even when it resumes on a different thread).

So the "context" doesn't appear to be the thread's working memory (i.e. thread local storage). So what does "context" contain? Therefore, what does it really mean to

> *marshal the continuation back to the original context captured*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I'm not totally wrong, `ConfigureAwait(false);` only means that the code which runs **after** the code you are awaiting, is not required to use the `SynchronizationContext` from before the await.

`SynchronizationContext` can be different things, as Stephen pointed out. Imagine you are in a web environment and your code after the await relies on `HttpContext.Current.Items`: this might not work anymore if you set `ConfigureAwait(false);`.

The following code in an MVC controller would throw an exception, for example:

```csharp
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["test"] = "test";

    var result = await SomethingAsync();
            
    return View();
}

private async Task<object> SomethingAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);

    // this will throw a nullpointer if ConfigureAwait is set to false
    return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["test"];
}
```

Your variable though is simply in the scope of the method and therefor it will be available, basically the method closure/scope, if this makes sense?

Comment: *"the code which runs after the code you are awaiting, must not run in the same SynchronizationContext."* is incorrect. A better way to say it is *"the code which runs after the code you are awaiting, Is not required to use the SynchronizationContext from before the await"*. If you await a task that is in the completed state you will likely still be using the same context as before the await because the code will have just gotten the result synchronously and never returned to the caller.

Comment: Makse sense, sorry I'm not native english so that was actually what I was trying to say. It is not always the case that the same sync context is not used because of what you said ;) Let me fix that phrase

Answer (score 9):

As I describe in my [`async` intro blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), the "context" is:

- `SynchronizationContext.Current`, unless it is `null`, in which case it is
- `TaskScheduler.Current`. Note that if there is no current task scheduler, then `TaskScheduler.Current` is the same as `TaskScheduler.Default`, which is a thread pool context.

The vast majority of the time, this is either a UI or ASP.NET request context (both types of `SynchronizationContext`), or else it's the thread pool context. Task scheduler contexts seldomly come into play.

Note that this context is just used to *schedule the continuation*. It doesn't do anything with marshaling; in your example `obj` is captured just like it would be if it were referenced from a lambda expression.

Comment: Thanks, can you elaborate "just used to schedule the continuation."? Does it mean "run continuation WHEN the UI thread OR ASP.NET thread OR any thread from the thread pool (depending on context) is free again"?

Comment: @DeepSpace101 It means it calls [`SynchronizationContext.Send`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.send(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`SynchronizationContext.Post`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post(v=vs.110).aspx) with the continuation delagate. It is up to the implementation of the context on how it processes that delegate (For the single threaded ones (WPF and Winforms) it is put it in to a message queue to be processed, for the pool based ones (ASP.net & thread pool) it grabs a resource from the pool.

Comment: In this example, what would happen to the fields of the object containing the `AnAsyncLibraryMethod()`? Are these also captured, or is some kind of barrier/lock generated?

Comment: @Denxorz: `this` is captured, and the fields hang off that. `await` does take care of [inserting a memory barrier automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28840239/263693) if the resuming code runs on a different thread.

Comment: @Stephen: Thanks, that makes sense. So that means that the `volatile` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53649830/2471080) is not needed?