# Do I need to use volatile for mutable object fields with async/await in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, roslyn, volatile

I've seen a lot of questions about this area (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54413147/1756750 , or https://stackoverflow.com/a/55139219/1756750 ), but unfortunately I haven't found anything in official documentation ( https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/11360 ).

Let's consider the following example.

```cs
public class Person
{
    // public byte[] name;        // (1)
    public volatile byte[] name;  // (2)

    public int nameLength;
}

public class PersonService
{
    private async Task ReadPerson(Person person)
    {
        // byte[] personBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("personPath.txt");          // (3)
        byte[] personBytes = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync("personPath.txt");  // (4)
        person.name = personBytes;
        person.nameLength = personBytes.Length;
    }

    public async Task HandlePerson()
    {
        Person person = new Person();
        await ReadPerson(person);
        
        string personName = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(person.name, 0, person.nameLength);
        Console.WriteLine(personName);
    }
}
```

The method `HandlePerson()` creates an empty `person` and calls the method `ReadPerson(person)`, which somehow gets a `person`. After that the `HandlePerson()` uses this object somehow. Such code pattern code be used, if we want to reuse object, or arrays.

Depends on implementation details of `ReadPerson(person)` (e.g., `(3)` vs `(4)`), this method could be executed on the same thread (which was used for `HandlePerson()`), or it can be rescheduled to another thread.

The next observation is both `Person.name` and `Person.nameLength` have atomic read/write (e.g. [What operations are atomic in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745440/what-operations-are-atomic-in-c) ). However, if I am not mistaken, it doesn't mean that we don't need `volatile` by default, because we still can see old state (`null value`) in general case (not specific for async/await).

I also tried to check [Jit ASM](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzgtgPgAgJgIwFgBQcAMACOSCsA3OlrkgHQCSA8sWiQMy4LYAKApgE4QD2AdugDe6bKOwB6cbiYAjAJ7B2AbQC62PmCjtCY3RKkAKJAEoRYuEwBuPADZhgASxvts8xavWbtoydgMJTejRdC2wHPmBPLQAZdj4Ac2AACzoAX3RGZjYuXj4AZS5LBwBjdiEzUQAHTgdLexc4AA5cADZsACV2MAATDm5+Az7c7Eqc/kDdYWC9MTdlNVH+vgAhBXYIbABebAAxJ3ZyTp6AQRsbVcUIAwAiRdzWeyTyYAAPYGvjHRnv/T8GCe+kjmHju/Au6y2uAAnLt9ocut1Tuc1hBjhA5HxijdQXwHslnm8Pl9fAYACwAmY48gaLSQnHgiB0H5UmnsWIJZJ0sYrFHkdmJFIVbDpIIhJhNVrYAASYD43WcQwGFOwUx+ir4I25kL47AA7tklgZPkKQjCjr1uQYccbpjMTeYkDgcQA5LyQvDkAAq7De5AAopieN1wvFyABVT07RrkADi7GAeWANQSVu51K8ABpsJgsyyvPzkjafngoamlq6tEWxCLUkA) for this code. I can see 2 different `lock cmpxchg [ecx], edi`, which could be a memory barriers, which were automatically created by the compiler, because of `async/await`. However, it could be something not-related to this. Also, C# compiler could optimize some memory barriers, because we use `x86`, which has pretty strict memory guaranties (compare to ARM64).

So, my question is, do we need to use `volatile` for mutable fields (e.g. `Person.name`, see `(1)` vs `(2)`), and if yes in what conditions?

Comment: Related: [Are you there, asynchronously written value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28871878/are-you-there-asynchronously-written-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've seen a lot of questions about this area (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54413147/1756750 , or https://stackoverflow.com/a/55139219/1756750 ), but unfortunately I haven't found anything in official documentation ( https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/11360 ).

I'm a little confused. You say that you've found SO answers for this, but no official docs. So... you ask on SO? Even if you get an answer, it's still an SO answer and not official docs.

> do we need to use volatile for mutable fields

No. There are sufficient memory barriers that you don't need `volatile` (or your own memory barriers), even if the code after `await` resumes on a different thread.

AFAIK, this is not actually documented anywhere officially, but consider a semi-proof-by-contradiction: if this *wasn't* the case, then the vast, vast majority of `async` code would be wrong, including lots of BCL and MS framework code. If it was that easy to write wrong `async` code, then there would be lots of documentation around it, articles complaining about pitfalls, etc. But none of that exists, and it is highly likely that the `async` code is correct.

Comment: Hello Stephen, thanks for the response. Yea, It looks silly that I am asking it on SO, even though I was thinking about official documentation :) 

I like your semi-proof-by-contradiction, and still wonder, why we don't have official statements about it. It is a bit stressful for me, when I need to write such code, but there is no official proof, that it is correct. Anyway, it is just my personal problem.