# Where is asynchronous continuations are queued in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, async-await, threadpool, synchronizationcontext

On legacy ASP.NET, the continuation of asynchronous method is queued to the request context (`AspNetSynchronizationContext`). But on ASP.NET Core, there is no such a `SynchronizationContext` (contextless).

So, where are asynchronous continuations queued in ASP.NET Core?

With this **contextless** condition, where is `HttpContext` information stored so that the threads from ThreadPool can refer to it?

Comment: The `HttpContext` is not stored centrally; it's stored in each controller class instance.

Comment: @Slaks, could you please tell me more detail? I think there is a way for multiple threads use the HttpContext object, right? So, which is the exact thread which HttpContext object is stored? Thank you!

Comment: No such mechanism exists.  Instead, you access the context from your class, which stores it in a field.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you to read [Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html) blog, and even [his book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920030171.do). In [this post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html) he talks about Synchronization Context in ASP.NET Core.

I highlight this paragraph:

> With the contextless ASP.NET Core approach, when an asynchronous
>   handler resumes execution, a thread is taken from the thread pool and
>   executes the continuation. The context queue is avoided, and there is
>   no “entering” of the request context necessary. In addition, the
>   async/await mechanism is highly optimized for the contextless
>   scenario. There’s simply less work to do for asynchronous requests.

Comment: Thanks @harkoded for the suggestion, I had read his post before. I just wonder how HttpContext could work in ASP.NET Core if it's serverless (_where is HttpContext information stored so that the threads from ThreadPool can refer to it?_). In legacy ASP.NET, we only can access to HttpContext object if we are on  UI thread. Accessing to `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["abc"]` will throw exception if we're not on UI thread. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29268001/what-does-context-exactly-mean-in-c-sharp-async-await-code