# Async method continuation in different thread - means cooperative two-thread access to object variable?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, synchronization, async-await

When I write in async method:

```
public class myGameLoop
{
    protected class GameObject
    {
      ....
    }

    protected GameObject [] myGameObjects;

    public async Task myMethod()
    {
        myPrologue(); //runs on caller thread 1
        await SomeLongOperation().ConfigureAwait(false); //runs on thread 2
        myContinuation(); //maybe on thread 2 or another one from pool
    }
}
```

there is a possibility that myContinuation() will be executed not in the same thread than myPrologue(). 
Imagine that caller thread is a draw thread of a game. Then if myPrologue() changes  non-atomic objects from myGameObjects array and myContinuation() works with them as well, we have unsynchronized access from 2 threads to object/array which can corrupt them.

Is it true or async/await has some synchronization stuff for such cases under the hood?
Or I should avoid using ConfigureAwait(false)? (I'm not sure how much threads can have Monogame draw thread synchronization context, so I set ConfigureAwait to false to prevent accidental deadlocks).

Comment: Well different calls of myMethod will also be executed on different threads, even not related to async\await, prologues and continuations. The fact that prologue and continuation runs on different threads doesn't change anything - they run sequentially.

Comment: say, myMethod runs only on draw thread, in draw loop. prologue changes objects and returns, then another code runs on draw thread, and so on (it's a draw loop!). And then SomeLongOperation() finishes and the remaining (myContinuation) code of myMethod() is called on another thread. While on draw thread another code (not from myMethod, but in draw loop) is working with game objects. See? I mean async/await let us write "plain" code for multithread work, but does them provide synchronization under the hood to keep illusion full?

Comment: If `myMethod` is called on the UI thread, then `myContinuation` will also run on the UI thread. This is a special case handled by the `await` keyword (thanks to the SynchronizationContext). So in this precise case you don't have to worry about concurrent accesses

Comment: @KooKiz but he explicitly uses ConfigureAwait(false) to prevent that.

Comment: Ugh, I missed that. Then indeed, concurrent accesses are possible

Comment: Still don't get your question. I mean, what kind of "under the hood" synchronization you might even expect here? You said yourself that some other code, not even in myMethod, might use the same objects together with myContinuation, so how it can be magically syncrhonized? All in all, there is no such under the hood synchronization anyway. Just handle concurrent access to the same objects as usual (locks and so on). I'd avoid removing ConfigureAwait precisely because of possible deadlocks in your case.

Comment: I think this questions is relevant, possibly even a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28840059/race-condition-in-async-await-code

Comment: :) guys, did somebody read the whole my post? It's not UI thread, it's draw thread. And yes, some code "together " with use the same objects, but myMethod and all this other code in draw thread are *in draw thread*. But the continuation of myMethod - is not! Regarding to possible duplicate: in his case it is I/O thread, that can be ready at once sometimes, which means sometimes continuation runs in the caller thread. So in "home testing" there is no race condition, but later in production it may occur. Or - as his variable is not volatile, it can be cached. Anyway I'll read the FAQ, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (I'm not sure how much threads can have Monogame draw thread synchronization context, so I set ConfigureAwait to false to prevent accidental deadlocks).

I think this is the misunderstanding here. If the draw thread has its own synchronization context that is specifically for that thread, then if you use a plain `await`, it would resume on that draw thread. And it seems to me that's what you *want*.

The reason for `ConfigureAwait(false)` is *not* to "prevent accidental deadlocks". It's just to notify the `await` that you **don't care** what context you need to resume on. So if you **do care** what context you resume on, then of course you *shouldn't* use `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

More info in my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) blog post.

Comment: Thanks, nice clarification! So you're saying no memory barriers (mentioned in FAQ) under the hood? So if I set ConfigureAwait(false) - now I'm on my own? Unfortunately I have to call async in sync code (porting big project from java/c#2.0). Moreover I'd prefer not to use async at all but msft gives no choice: network, files, services are using async. I used to use callbacks. async looks cute but I have to know what's inside to use it right way. It's not just black box,and I think it's very wrong way of making languages and libraries. I'll read your blog, thank you!

Comment: I've read your blog and msft docs, and I've found out that there's no magic added by compiler to avoid race conditions. So please confirm that I understand right : in continuation of async method being called in another thread (configureAwait(false)) it's insecure to access global non-volatile and non-atomic variables directly without any kind of multithread locks?

Comment: @Tertium: There *are* memory barriers; there is *not* synchronization. When accessing shared data from multiple threads, you need to protect it yourself - this is equally true whether the code is async or sync.

Comment: what does mean memory barrier then?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier In this case, it just means that you can set a value before an `await`, and after the `await`, the variable contains that same value, regardless of whether you resume on the same thread or not. Without memory barriers, this would not be true.